# Can't receive data from wiki api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

My code is in codepen and it's link is:
https://codepen.io/mlestina/pen/OZpOQW?editors=1111

I can never receive any data back from the Wiki API.

The Contr-Shift-J readout is:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=dsfds&callback=jQuery331010723807837372779_1525209741598&_=1525209741599”.  index.html:1
An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can remove its sandboxing. OZpOQW
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://static.codepen.io/assets/telefon/bold/af889c53-1ee3-4868-8fdc-2b310d587b50-3-b7a87e0fbd213943fae0c0ef5985635dd43fa9c24876b2725127a13ccaf4ab6a.woff. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). (unknown)
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Telefon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: https://static.codepen.io/assets/telefon/bold/af889c53-1ee3-4868-8fdc-2b310d587b50-3-b7a87e0fbd213943fae0c0ef5985635dd43fa9c24876b2725127a13ccaf4ab6a.woff unknown:1:24452
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Hitler&callback=jQuery33109582690097080016_1525209907566&_=1525209907567”.  index.html:1
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!  OZpOQW
```

The HTML is:

```
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="a" id="a"><br>

  <button onclick="passToJ()">Search</button>

</form>
</body>
```

and the Javascript is:

```
function passToJ() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('a').value;
    console.log("inside function, searchTerm is: ", searchTerm, " and x is: ", x);
    var wikiLink = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        url: wikiLink,      
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        },
        error: function() {
        console.log('error occurred');
    }
})};
```

Comment: Have you read that error message? I think the message is pretty clear

Comment: Formatting & spelling

Comment: If it was clear, I wouldn't be asking this question.  Am still in the dark on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer from another forum.

It was either;

1) including   event.preventDefault(); in the javascript code, or

2) eliminate the Form and /Form tags from the HTML

Matt